# printing several classes with one loop, java

Tags: java, arrays, object, printing

//Consider the code(*)

```
    class Whatever {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1[10];
        CLass2 c2 = new Class2[10];
        Class3 c3 = new Class3[10];

    void printArray(Object[] a) {
        for(Object b: a) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I want to print the names saved in these classes
They're already initialized in another class, and have this.name = name set
and unique for all of them.
Thus when trying to print them using:

Which for instance prints

Class1@124124124 // the address

Then how do I access actual members of the class passed into the method?

Is this actually possible at all?

Comment: What do you mean by members? It methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can override `toString()` method in your `Class1`, `Class2` and so on like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return this.memberX + " " + this.memberY;
}
```

which will print memberX and memberY. `System.out.println(x);` invokes `x.toString();` by default.

Comment: Tell me how you override toString on a Class object?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I see you edited your comment. But I still don't understand your question...

Comment: Original poster has arrays of Class objects that he's printing. The printout even says Class1@... You can override toString on the Object you designed, but that will have no effect if you call System.out.print(myObj.getClass());

Comment: You're wrong, read the question carefully. There are 3 arrays of Class1, Class2 and Class3 (Class<ONE> Class<TWO> Class<THREE>)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using the word "class" correctly in your question. By "Then when I want to print the names saved in these classes" I'm going to assume you mean the names saved in the *instances* of Class1, Class2, etc... initialized and stored in the given arrays.

Seems like you want your classes to share some functionality. You say that you have a name field for all of them - why not specify through an interface that they truly can do that?

```
public interface Namable{
    public String getName();
}
```

Then make all of your classes implement this interface...

```
public class Class1 implements Namable{ ... }
public class Class2 implements Namable{ ... }
etc...
```

Then you can change the signature of your method to take in an array of Namables, each of which you can call the getName() method on.

```
void printArray(Namable[] a) {
    for(Namable b: a) {
        System.out.println(b.getName());
    }
}
```